# Question about pronoun who

Tags: sentence, pronouns

I was writing something like: *Speaking is an umbrella term itself who encompasses grammar, vocabulary, fluency and accuracy and pronunciation.*

Herein lies two problem, 1.can i use who here?
2.does this sentence make sense? i'm not  sure if i used umbrella term properly here

Please help me and do not be so pedantic, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

> Speaking is an umbrella term itself which encompasses grammar, vocabulary, fluency, accuracy and pronunciation.

1. Can I use who here?

No we use *who* to refer to persons/people, if you’re referring to inanimate objects/abstract subjects, it is preferred to use “which”.

2. Does this sentence make sense? I’m not sure if I used umbrella term properly here

No but with my suggested revisions, it will make sense. Yes, you used the term “umbrella term” correctly.

Answer (score 1):

'Who' is usually only used for people. I would use 'which'. Some people use 'that'. I would also remove the first 'and' from your sentence and place inverted commas around 'speaking'.